# Redirecting specific Domains to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess

My domain www.abc.com is now redirecting to https://www.abc.co.uk

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

These code works exactly what I want. After that I created a subdomain. www.x.abc.co.uk
Now I want to redirect that to http://x.abc.co.uk (without https)

I used this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^x\.abc\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But browser says it has redirect loop.

How can do that?

Answer (score 1):

If these are two different htaccess files then give this a try.

```
RewriteEngine On
#redirect www.x.abc.co.uk without www to http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.x\.abc\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://x.abc.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I modified your original rule so you don't have two rewrite rules and still direct to www.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.abc.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: +1 for taking extra effort to combines 2 rules into one.